# Get latest free index of DB?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

How can I access to last DB index?

For example, in my DB I create records with automatically generated names, like `news-post1`, `news-post2`, etc. To create name for new record, I need to access latest DB index.

In my case, I need to edit names of images like above. I already know how to access file extension, but not index of DB

```
def generate_image_name(obj, file_data):
    img_extension = path.splitext(file_data)[1]
    img_name = "news-img"+<?db.Index?>+img_extension
```

Comment: You should insert the record into the database, let it create the auto-index, see what index number you got, and then, *if actually necessary*, update a field in the record using that index number. Anything else is prone to *race conditions*. But since the index number is already part of the record, consider whether it’s really necessary to store it as part of the record redundantly.

Comment: @deceze Ok, but how can i access index after creating record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find what i exactly what i searching for.
For exmaple, at the moment i have 2 news records.

```
>>> News.query.all()[-1]
<News 2>
>>> News.query.all()[-1].id
2
```